# Outer overlaps in Terra R

Tags: r, merge, overlapping-features, terra

I am relatively new to R and GIS in R especially. Just recently started to quit QGIS to use terra in R. I have tried a couple of times to do overlaps (intersect) and also to merge a data frame into a SpatVector Object with success for inner joins (conserving only shared polygons/ features).

However I have not been able to find a way to do outer joins or overlaps, in the way all.x and all.y would work for merging data frames. Also, I have not found a discussion on the topic here or elsewhere.

I know that you can work this around extracting the difference and appending it to the overlayed result. But it would be incredibly helpful to have this capability in the merge and intersect functions in terra.

I was about to put a ticket on the [terra repo](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) but before I wanted to ask:

**Do the merge and intersect functions have this "all" option?**

Comment: Do this in sf and then, if necessary,  coerce into terra vector object.

Comment: As-is, `merge` does not work with `all.y=TRUE` if that would add records that are not in `x`. This avoids creating records with empty geometries. But it would not take much to allow it. The github site would be a good place to request that (especially if you can provide a good use case for it)